# Problem with Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

in my `form.py` I have a class `StudentsForm`:

```
class StudentsForm(ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        students  = kwargs.pop('students')
        course    = kwargs.pop('course')
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        CHOICE_LIST = [('', '----')]
        i = 1
        for itm in students:
            CHOICE_LIST.append((i, itm))
            i += 1

        self.fields['students'].choices = CHOICE_LIST
        self.fields['students'].initial = ['']
        self.fields['course'].choices = [(1, course), (2, '----'
                )]
        self.fields['course'].initial = [1]

    class Meta:

        model = StudCourse
        fields = (
            'course',
            'students',
            )

        widgets = {
            'course': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control',
                    'placeholder': 'Select course',
                    'style': 'color: crimson; background-color:ivory;'
                    }),
            'students': forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={'class': 'form-control'
                    , 'placeholder': 'Select students',
                    'style': 'color: crimson; background-color:ivory;'
                    }),
            }
```

my `view.py`

```
def test(request):
    #team = get_team(request)

    # here the second students is a query set of model Student, 2nd course is an object of model      #Course
    form = StudentsForm(students=students, course=course)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = StudentsForm(request.POST, students=students, course=course)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('home')

    if team.exists():
        return render(request, 'app/students_goal_form.html', {'form':form})
```

my `students_goal_form.html`

```
{% block content %}
<section id="students_form">
    <div class="row">
        <p>&nbsp</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3"></div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <form action="" method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {{ form.as_p }}
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
                    <i class="icon-circle-arrow-right icon-large"></i> Save
                    </button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <p>&nbsp</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <p>&nbsp</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <p>&nbsp</p>
    </div>
</section>
{% endblock %}
```

It works correctly without adding `students=students`, `course=course` to form (without modifying `__init__` ) , but I need to filter query set in case of `students` and also need a specific (only one) `course`. I have also modified `__init__` in form to add possibility to choose nothing.

my model `StudCourse`:

```
class StudCourse(models.Model):
    course    = models.ForeignKey(Course, verbose_name='Course', on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name='+', blank=True, null=True, help_text=u'You can choose specific course or group of students')
    students = models.ManyToManyField(Student, null=True,  blank=True, symmetrical=False, related_name='student_name')

    def get_students(self):
        return "\n ".join([p.end_user_id for p in self.students.all()])

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Title: : ' + self.course
```

Why I have an Error when in view the form is validating: `Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.`
How to modify my form which accept to choose nothing?

[UPDATE] my `Student` model:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name                = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Name')
    lastname            = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Lastname')
    status              = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Is Active?')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + ' ' + self.lastname
```

in view I set to the form next:

```
students = Student.objects.filter(status=true)
```

Answer (score 1):

The code above doesn't explain in detail how do you generate content for the `students` variable that you pass to the form, but I guess the issue could be there.
The list of choices for the student's field is generated in a way that in each pair (id, object) the `id` is a number in a sequence but not the real id of an object.

```py
        CHOICE_LIST = [('', '----')]
        i = 1
        for itm in students:
            CHOICE_LIST.append((i, itm))
            i += 1

        self.fields['students'].choices = CHOICE_LIST
```

instead, you should use the primary key as an id to reflect the structure of your database

```py
CHOICE_LIST.append((itm.pk, itm))
```

Comment: I've added my Student model and execution for students in view.

Comment: Right, and it looks good. I still think you should apply my above suggestion and it should help with your issue. `Students` model doesn't have any custom primary key and it will be generated automatically. Using it instead of simple enumeration as you do now should fix your issue.

Comment: Now my choices looks like: `(45, <Student: Student1>)
(46, <Student: Eweline Dragan>)
(None, None)`, but I am still can't choose None option

Comment: You can of course control what you have as a label for your choices and that doesn't have to be the Student object itself e.g. `CHOICE_LIST.append((itm.pk, itm.name))`. You could prepend an empty option to the list of your choices like `('', '-----')` and that should give you a way to not chose the student.